# SQL Update multiple rows based on ID

Tags: php, mysql

How to update rows based on entered ids into input?
Eg. 20,23,24 update 'price'
My code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE product SET price=price+(".$reduction."/1.23) WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
<input name="reduction" type="text" >
<input name="id" type="text" value="id" > <input name="submit" value="ID"   type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't post a question that you haven't tried to solve. You should attempt to solve it yourself first. If you have tried, you can then include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "IN" function like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE product SET price=price+(".$reduction."/1.23) WHERE id in('".$id."')");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your query like below:-

```
<form method="post">
<input name="reduction" type="text" >
<input name="id" type="text" value="id" > <input name="submit" value="ID"   type="submit">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE product SET price=price+(".$reduction."/1.23) WHERE id IN ('".$id."')"); // instead of = you have to use `IN`
}
```